# Button inside another button in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, button, swiftui

How can I make the inner `Button` execute its action instead of the outer one always being performed?

```
struct Foo: View {
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: { print("alloha") }) {
            HStack {
                Button(action: { print("hello") }) {
                    Image(systemName: "circle.fill")
                }
                Text("world")
                Spacer()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: try to use the Outer one as View and put the tap, fi you don't need the any effect on outer/parent Button.
With this in there inner button will work normally, and when you tap on outer View you will get the action.

Comment: If I add just tap then it is not obvious for the user that the outer view is reacting to touch.

Comment: You can also use `.overlay` to put the smaller button on top

Comment: ↑ This from TruMan1 is the way to do it and will achieve the correct UI effect for each button. Overlay one button on top of the other, and it will work.

Answer (score 1):

It works, just give enough space for internal button, so hit testing could designate which button to activate, like in below example. (Tested with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4)

[image: demo]

```
struct Foo: View {
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: { print("alloha") }) {
            HStack {
                Button(action: { print("hello") }) {
                    Image(systemName: "circle.fill").padding() // << more space !!
                        .border(Color.red) // << for testing
                }
                Text("world")
                Spacer()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No it does not. I was using fixed frame of recommended 44 point for icon. This particular code is used as simplification. In production grade app where an outer view is say a cell and the inner is a like icon it does not work.

Comment: Hi, @Asperi
And is there a way to disable the outer button's pressed state when the inner button is pressed?

Comment: @BalázsPapp you can use a ZStack to layer each button.

Answer (score -8):

I am curious why you are adding button inside a button? I could use Two Buttons within a HStack like below. It will be obvious to user when tapping each buttons.

```
HStack {
    Button(action: { print("hello") }) {
        Image(systemName: "circle.fill")
    }

    Button(action: {
        print("World")
    }) {
        Text("World")
    }
}
```

Comment: Because product owners do not get UX

Comment: @Ivan Does above view structure works for you? Based on your question, above alternative is more graceful than button inside button. Else you need to tell what exact structure of view your are doing in your production because you mentioned your question example is just a simplification version.